# Export variable to other files discordjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, discord.js

I changed my command handler and am no longer exporting anything from profileData (used to be command handler file). The file is checking for their profile and holding the data in profileData, or if they don't have on then create one for them. I want to export the profileData to be used in other files instead of querying in every single command. How can I achieve this. I have tried putting module.exports and exports.profileData = profileData all over the place and nothing works im just lost on how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

profileData-

```js
const profileModel = require("../../models/profileSchema");
  module.exports =  (client) => {
    client.on("message", async (message) => {
      const prefix = 's!'
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
  
  try {
    const profileData = await profileModel.findOne({ userID: message.author.id });
    if (!profileData) {
      let profile = await profileModel.create({
        userID: message.author.id,
        serverID: message.guild.id,
        coins: 10,
        bank: 0,
      });
      profile.save();
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})
}
module.exports.config = {
  displayName: 'Profile Data',
  dbName: 'PROFILEDATA',
  loadDBFirst: true
}
```

balance-

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { profileData } = require("../../Features/client/profileData");
module.exports = {
  name: "balance",
  aliases: ["bal"],
  category: "Economy",
  cooldown: "20s",
  permissions: ["ADMINISTRATOR"],
  maxArgs: 0,
  description: "Check your wallet and bank balance!",
  execute: async ({ message, client }) => {
    let balPlaceholder = "'s balance";

    const BalEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("#0bbffc")
      .setAuthor("Saoul 2")
      .setTitle(`${message.author.username}${balPlaceholder}`)
      .addFields(
        { name: " Wallet:", value: `${profileData.coins}`, inline: true },
        { name: " Bank:", value: `${profileData.bank}`, inline: true }
      )
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter(
        `Command Requested By ${message.author.tag}`,
        client.user.displayAvatarURL()
      );
    message.channel.send(BalEmbed);
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly: you want to export the profileData, and if none can be found, create a new profile and use that. The following snippet might solve your problem.

```js
const profileModel = require("../../models/profileSchema");


let data = getData(client);
exports.data = data;

async function getData(client) {
  client.on("message", async(message) => {
    const prefix = 's!'
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    try {
      const profileData = await profileModel.findOne({
        userID: message.author.id
      });
      if (!profileData) {
        let profile = await profileModel.create({
          userID: message.author.id,
          serverID: message.guild.id,
          coins: 10,
          bank: 0,
        });
        profile.save();
        return profile;
      } else {
        return profileData;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  })
}

module.exports.config = {
  displayName: 'Profile Data',
  dbName: 'PROFILEDATA',
  loadDBFirst: true
}
```

Comment: This would work if it would work with my command handler. I have to define client through the built in command handler. module.exports =  (client) => { Maybe theres a way to do that within what you sent?

Comment: @Saoul you could add client with: getData(client)

e.g.:
let data = getData(client);
async function getData(client) { . . .

Comment: I tried that and it client is undefined, I also tried putting what you sent inside of the module.exports = (client) => { and that runs with no issues but still leaves the data undefined in my commands.

Comment: Maybe coins aren't correctly defined in your profileSchema?
That would me my first guess now...
Everything else works now?

Comment: Christoph Blüm This used to work smoothly as this code was in my command handler so when someone ran a command it was just built into it. Now I switched to wokcommands so I dont need to have my own. Theres nothing wrong with the database or anything its just that I can't figure out how to export the profileData variable to be used in my commands. Thats why I don't understand why I can't both import client and export profileData with the solution I have. Import client with module.exports = (client) => through the command handler. Then your solution to export profileData.

Answer (score 0):

This is all I needed to get the function to run when a message is sent through the command handler.

```js
module.exports = {
    getData: async (message) => {
        try {
```